# Is my potentiometer broken?

Tags: resistance, potentiometer

So i ordered this cheap 100 ohm ten turn pot from ebay: [Potentiometer](http://www.ebay.com/itm/182081894163?_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649&var=483220540951&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT)

The problem is that it doesn't work as a normal pot (or it is broken).

When i check resistance from pin 2 to pin 3, everything is working fine, i can turn the wiper and the resistance is changing, however, if i check from pin 2 to pin 1, it shows 100 Ohms resistance all the time, no matter how much i turn the wiper. Is it supposed to do that or have i wired it wrong? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried measuring the resistance between pins 1 and 3?

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes, everything is working fine there. When i turn the pot half the way it shows 50 ohms.

Comment: So, is the pot working just fine except the pins seem mislabeled?

Comment: No.. I mean, if i check one of my other pots i have laying around. Resistance from pin 1 - 2, and from pin 2 - 3 should react the same way. It should not show the max resistance of the pot all the time right?

Comment: In a 'normal' pot, you'd have variable resistance between pins 1-2 and 2-3, and the full resistance between pins 1-3. So apparently this does just what it's supposed to, with only the difference of the order of pins.

Comment: I'm gonna test the resistance and treat the other pins as the wiper. Will post back the results.

Comment: Edit: Forgot, I don't have any variable between pins 2-3. only 1-2.

Comment: Nice to know Bourns pots are considered cheap, they are usually of a decent quality and at first glance I was worried you had a pirate part if it was not working correctly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your pot is probably fine, but the terminal numbering is confusing you. Hopefully this image will make it clear:-

[image]

Comment: Why should the pins be numbered like that?

Comment: I just tried it! and you where right.. I feel so stupid.. damn ebay stuff who labeles things weird xD Thank you very much Bruce!! :D

Comment: datasheet confirms: http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/54/590-776468.pdf

Comment: The convention is to number from one end of the track to the other, with the wiper connection on pin 2. But physically this pot has its track spiraling around the inside wall of the body with the wiper in the center, so the wiper connection has to come out the back end rather than between other two terminals. http://i2.wp.com/www.scienceprog.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/multiturn_potentiometer.jpg

Comment: This is my first time using multi-turn pots, Thank you for the detailed explination! Learned something new hehe